# Grep printing a line that doesn't contain a set of numbers

Tags: grep

I'm trying to get Grep to print all lines in a txt file that do not contain the numbers 834.  When I try "grep [^834] file.txt"  it still prints all the lines containing 834 but just doesn't highlight them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask grep to print all lines that contain a pattern consisting of a character that is not a 8, 3 or 4. Depending on what your file consists of, this will probably find almost anything. 
To show "everything but" grep has the -v switch. E.g. something like grep -v "8\|3\|4" should work. Or if you specifically want to throw out the number 834: grep -v 834

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know how I would use grep to print lines where a last name begins with K or k?

Comment: Try grep " [Kk][a-z]+ ". This would select a word enclosed in spaces, beginning with K or k and one or more alphanumericals. grep unfortunately has no way to tell if the word is a last name...

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
grep -v '[834]' file
```

From `man grep`

```
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
          is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: yeah the [] didn't work.  When trying the command without the [] it worked fine.  Thanks

Comment: @Cyrus based on the OP's question I interpreted the requirement as 'all lines containing none of the digits 8,3,4' - so no

Comment: Do either of you know how I would use grep to print lines where a last name begins with K or k?

Comment: Well `grep` has no concept of what a "last name" means, however you could search for lines containing any word **starting with** the letter K using `grep -i '\<K'` (the `-i` makes it case insensitive). OTOH if the file is structured into **fields** (like `firstname  lastname`) then you might want to look at tools like `awk` instead.

Comment: so I'm searching through a file of people that is structured like below

John Smith 555-555-5555 Harvard Square, Boston

I'm interested in finding all the LAST names that start with the letter K or k, so the second word on a line starting with the letter K or k.  How do I do that?

Comment: I suggest you post a whole new question for that